# math cases package problem

Tags: math-operators, cases

I am preparing a presentation with beamer.

I want to use a math formulas that contains a cases

```
\begin{cases}{|x|=}
x, & for $x \geq 0$\\
-x, & for $x < 0$
\end{cases}
```

the problem in that my result is in this picture

[image]

---

Thanks for your interest

Here is my result, I am using the template in [this link](http://melmorabity.fedorapeople.org/latex/beamer/old/beamer-goddard/beamer-goddard-0.1.tar.bz2)

[image]

Comment: What specifically is the problem here? The colours? The placement of the content? It would be best if you include the exact problem in your post, and also provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) rather than a code snippet. It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`. You should also include the current theme.

Comment: If you are satisfied with my answer, please kindly accept it to make the status of your question answered rather than unanswered. You optionally upvote my answer as well. :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\abovedisplayskip=0pt\relax% don't use this line in your production
\[
\lvert x\rvert=
\begin{cases}
x& \text{for $x>0$}\\
0& \text{for $x=0$}\\
-x& \text{for $x<0$}
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Beamer version

```
\documentclass[mathserif]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Absolute value}
\[
\lvert x\rvert=
\begin{cases}
\onslide<2->{x& \text{for $x>0$}}\\
\onslide<3->{0& \text{for $x=0$}}\\
\onslide<4->{-x& \text{for $x<0$}}
\end{cases}
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried this method but the problem still appears

Comment: @djanahana: What is your problem?

Comment: The math cases didn' looking good

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `for $x < 0$` you should write, e.g., `\mbox{for $x < 0$}`. It gives the proper spacing and fonts.

Comment: Using `\text` is better than `\mbox`.

Comment: i had the same result

Comment: @You And the andvantages in this context are...

Comment: Semantics mostly (I won't pretend to get the technical details right). Writing text in math mode should always imply using `\text` IMHO.

Comment: @You "Writing text in math mode should always imply using \text". But `\text` is absent in base LaTeX. It is `amsmath` macro.

Comment: Lots of things aren't in base LaTeX. \mbox had problems earlier on.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke `cases` is an `amsmath` envionment as well, so I don't see the point. Besides, I have yet to encounter a document that has math but no `amsmath`.

Answer (score 0):

The `cases*` environment (from `mathtools` package) makes the second part (after &) in text mode automatically.